# Wrong Name in Social Secrity Card

Tags: usa, immigration, social-security

I am new immigrant and I received my car with an error in the name. what to do ?

Comment: Was there any letter or documentation accompanying the card with guidance on what to do in this situation?

Comment: [This Social Security webpage](https://secure.ssa.gov/poms.nsf/lnx/0110205120) explains that the Social Security Administration only considers the first and last name to be important (with occasional exceptions). If your issue is about a middle name or a suffix the webpage may help.

Answer (score 5):

According to the Social Security Administration, you can [get a corrected card free of charge by submitting a new application documenting the correct name](https://faq.ssa.gov/en-us/Topic/article/KA-01981).

Since you would presumably be submitting the same documents you used in the initial application, you may want to include a short letter explaining what the error is.  It should state the name the name exactly as you want it to be on the card.